# WCF wsdl wsdl:import location,soap:address location are having machine name?

Tags: .net, wcf, wsdl

Hi
 We developed web service using WCF service and hosted on Windows 2003 server machine with IIS 5.1. WCF hosted on **basicHttpBinding**.
 when try to access wsdl of service **"*.svc?wsdl"** it generating wrong wsdl, that wsdl cannot be used java and php clients. 
when I check the wsdl in

```
<wsdl:import namespace="xxxxx" location="http://machine name/xxx/xxx.svc?wsdl=wsdl0"/> 
<soap:address location="http://machine name/xcxx/xxx.svc" />
```

How can i remove machine and replace it with my web site url?
How can i generate full WSDL document like what ASMX web service will generate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I browsed net and got solution for my problem
the following helped me a lot. 
Hope these will be help some other.

nRk

For generating flat WSDL
http://my-tech-talk.blogspot.com/2008/07/adding-flatwsdl-to-wcf-webservice.html
http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cweyer/2007/05/improving-wcf-interoperability-flattening-your-wsdl.html
http://isinghblog.blogspot.com/2009/03/wcf-service-and-adobe-livecycle_10.html
For chaning host name which will reflect in wsdl address
http://forums.asp.net/p/1096811/1659596.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I fixed it:

1. In your IIS bindings, be sure to include a host name.
2. Install this hotfix: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971842.  There are links on the KB page to download the hotfix.  The hotfix required a reboot for me.
3. To "activate" the hotfix, add the following to the behavior element in your web.config:

```
    <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
        <defaultPorts>
            <add port="80" scheme="http" />
            <add port="443" scheme="https" />
        </defaultPorts>
    </useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
```

Comment: Matt, http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/KB971842 that hofix specifically says it is not for Win 2003 server. How did you apply it to 2003?

Comment: @Roger, actually it says specifically that if you're on Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2 then you should apply a different hotfix (KB971842).  If you're on Windows 2003 then you SHOULD apply the fix for KB971842.  http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/KB971842